# WordPress Count Number Value in Table Row SQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress data table as an image. My user rating is (max 5*).

[image]

(In my data I have 2 rating 5* for postid = 1 / 1 rating 4* for postid = 1). How do I echo number rating 5* for postid = 1 (is 2)? Similar for rating 4* / 3*...1*.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement could be `"SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE postid = 1 AND rating = 5"`

Comment: `$results = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM acfpro_all_in_one_post_ratings WHERE postid= 1 and rating=5');
echo $results;`
Thanks @Luke